# ENOENT / FileNotFoundException Upon Using ContentResolver on URI

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Error(s) are:

```
Caused by android.system.ErrnoException
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
/storage/emulated/0/Download/File-16.ext: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

*(File name/extension changed slightly for privacy.)*

---

The line of code is simply

```
inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);
```

Where data is the non-null URI `intent.getData();`

It works for 99% of users, but there's quite a few that report this crash silently. I can't figure out why though?

I've logged some of the URIs that cause this but see no pattern:

- file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/File-16.ext
- file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/12APK%2BOBB.NESTV.zip
- file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Figure%20Submission%20umdertale
- content://com.google.android.apps.searchlite.fileprovider/downloadfile/storage/emulated/0/Download/MKX-Scorpion-vs-Sub-Zero.zip
- content://downloads/all_downloads/2249

Also no consistency in device/android version either. Can't find any questions on this, only questions with answers saying to use ContentResolver on URIS, which I am in this case.

Comment: Either the underlying content is gone, is not available under that name, or you lack permissions to access it.